# Correct way to use If statements

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Need help understanding proper way of using "if elseif else" statements. CODE A below works but is it correct? Am I allowed to end the statement with "elseif"? Or are "if" statements supposed to end with either "endif" or "else" ?

**CODE A: This code works**

But notice it does not end with "endif" or "else".

```
if ( is_page( 'contact' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/contact'); }
elseif ( is_page( 'policy' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/policy'); }
elseif ( is_page( 'about' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/about'); }
elseif ( is_page( 'terms' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/terms'); } 
?>
```

.
Are all "if statements" supposed to end with "endif"? If yes, can you show me the code? 
In CODE B below using "endif" results in White Screen error.

**CODE B: endif does NOT work**

```
if ( is_page( 'contact' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/contact'); }
elseif ( is_page( 'policy' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/policy'); }
elseif ( is_page( 'about' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/about'); }
elseif ( is_page( 'terms' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/terms'); } 
endif;
?>
```

.
Is the last "elseif" supposed to be "else" instead? If yes, can you show me the code? 
In CODE C below using "else" results in White Screen error.

**CODE C: "else" instead of "elseif" does NOT work**

```
if ( is_page( 'contact' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/contact'); }
elseif ( is_page( 'policy' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/policy'); }
elseif ( is_page( 'about' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/about'); }
else ( is_page( 'terms' ) ) { get_template_part('inc/terms'); }
?>
```

Comment: [**PHP - if**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). You don't need an `endif` (the brackets `{` and `}` decide what is inside the condition and when it ends). The reason `CODE C` does not work is because `else` is "if none of these, then do this". If you want another condition you need to use `elseif`. In your last example, simply switch out `else` with `elseif`. (**essentially, the answer is that CODE A is the correct way of doing it.**). You **only** use [`endif`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) if you've used `if (condition):` (note the :)

Comment: Have you considered using a switch for this? It would be easier to read!

Comment: You could also use an array mapping the pages to the paths, that would be a bit easier to maintain.

Comment: @joroen can you show me how to convert CODE A to "array mapping the pages to the paths" ? I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endif is only used with the "alternate syntax" http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php
personally i wouldn't use it, but its up to you.

per your "else" question .. it is optional. its the "failsafe" ... if nothing else matches then it is executed. if you don't  have an "else" and all of your elseif's fail, then nothing will be done in that code block.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `:` and `endif` **OR** curly brackets (`{}`), but not both. Either of these syntaxes will work

```
if( something_is() ) :
  do something;
endif;
```

or

```
if( something_is() ) {
  do something;
}
```

The second is actually the prefered way as it is easier to debug as nearly all code editors support this syntax. The first is quite hard to debug as it is not supported by most of the code editors

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating both methods! I tried checkmarking two answers but it didn't work =/ By the way, do you know how to convert CODE A to "array mapping the pages to the paths" as suggested by joroen?

Comment: Your welcome. Ya, you can only accept one answer. The answer you've accepted is much more informational than mine :-). Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

people tend to use this syntax in php-based templates, because it kinda looks template-ish

```
   <? if (something) : ?>
    <b>Yea!</b>
    <? else: ?>
    <p>nothing</p>
    <? endif; ?>
```

as for backend stuff its recommended to use this syntax

```
if (something) { bar(); } 
elseif (other)
{
  yes();
}
?>
```

php also allows this

```
if (something) myThing() elseif (that) other(); else doNot();
```

bottom line, you can only combine one type of syntax

Comment: `if (something) myThing() elseif (that) other(); else doNot();` Don't know why this syntax ever came into existance. It is a nightmare to debug. Although it is 100% valid PHP, I do not use it at all. Curly brackets still stays the best

Comment: completely agree with that, was just pointing out what is possible to do

Answer (score 0):

I would say Code A. 
`else` is used when you want to say:

```
if(/*option;*/)
{
//code
}
elseif(/*another option;*/)
{
//code
}else /*Any other options beside the above*/ {/*code;*/}
```

But in your code you have a special case in the last condition. So CodeA.